# How do I acquire DELETE permissions on Facebook Graph API (PHP SDK)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

Simple, imagine I am posting a wall post or an event on a random Facebook Page from a PHP script, and I want to delete the item. I simply use this :

```
$facebook->api('/'.FacebookId,'DELETE');
```

Of course, the FacebookId is structured like : userid_postid

But that doesn't work. To see why, I simply go to this URL :

https://graph.facebook.com/" + postID + "?method=delete&access_token=" + AccessToken;

Here is the result :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

By lurking around stackoverflow, I found this bug : http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12777
It is still not resolved.

So if anyone knows how to get this permission, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/):

> You can delete a post **as long as your application created the post**.
>   You delete a post by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to the POST_ID
>   object with publish_stream permission.

Is this the case? Has your app created the post? does it have the "publish_stream" permissions?

I just tried it using the graph explorer, I created a post by POSTing to the *me/feed*, got back an id (USERID_POSTID) and then issues a DELETE request to the id, and it worked well (the returned response was "true").

Comment: Yes, my app is issuing the POST and DELETE, but not on /me/feed, that's on /page_id/feed.

Here are my permissions : 

 - manage_pages
 - publish_stream
 - offline_access
 - create_event
 - publish_actions

But according to what you said, I went on graph.facebook.com/post_id?method=delete&access_token=access_token_for_the_page, and yeah, it worked.

So I think I'll get around with that. Thanks a lot Nitzan!

Comment: One note, you cannot delete comments on Ratings (reviews) even if you created the comment. Per docs: Reviews are not Page posts, so comments on reviews can not be removed by a Page as they can with Page posts.